# not able to understand the output, the code is running properly : <statsmodels.tools.testing.Holder object at 0x07EED870>

Tags: python-3.x

I am not able to understand the output:

Not able to understand the error

```
from statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.vecm import coint_johansen

import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df_x = pd.read_csv('pfc2.csv',index_col=0)

df_y = pd.read_csv('REC2.csv',index_col=0)

dy = pd.DataFrame({'x':df_x['Close'],'y':df_y['Close']})

coint_johansen(dy ,0, 1)

print(coint_johansen(dy ,0, 1))
```

Comment: The output is <statsmodels.tools.testing.Holder object at 0x07EED870>

Answer (score -1):

```
result = coint_johansen(dy ,0, 1)

result.eig, result.lr1
```

You should read like the above code.